# Movie ID: Cops rewarded with taking a hit

Tags: story-identification, movie

I remember seeing a movie in the mid 80s/early 90s that took place in a dystopian metropolitan future where whenever the police arrested a perp, they were rewarded with taking a hit of some sort of drug from a device strapped onto their chest. This was not a major plot point, just a small scene near the beginning to set the feel of dystopia.

Can anyone help me identify the movie?

Ironically, once identified, I’ll probably be familiar with the movie as a whole. I just can’t remember which movie this scene was in. Some possibilities: Judge Dredd, Robocop, etc.

I should also add that I was just a kid at the time. This was either a movie on (network) TV or one that my parents/older brothers rented.

Comment: Reminds me of Q in Star Trek: The Next Generation, when he references soldiers during the 21st century "post-atomic horror" being motivated and controlled by drugs.

Comment: Definitely not the first *Robocop*. I don't think it's a *Judge Dredd* movie either because a search on that turned up nothing. *Robocop 2* has a corrupt police officer, Duffy, who is addicted to Nuke, the illegal drug at the center of the plot. In *Leon* AKA *The Professional*, DEA agent Morgan Stansfield (Gary Oldman) takes some kind of pill that is presumably an illegal drug before murdering people or at other significant times. Just eliminating possibilities.

Comment: My first thought was *Strange Days*, but after looking at it, I don't see any indication that the police are getting drug hits.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This may not be it, but I agree with @Vanguard3000's comment. It sounds like one of the early scenes from the first episode of Star Trek: The Next Generation where Q recreates the courts of 21st century "post atomic horror" Earth. Here's a screenshot for reference.

[image]

Comment: It’s not exactly how I remembered it, but if that’s not it, TNG totally stole it. So I’m guessing that’s it.